# Correct number `x` divided into integer `y` parts and rounded to `2` decimal places so the sum is `x` again

Tags: java, mysql, excel, math

I want to show the values in the excel sheet  such that

when `x` is divided by integer `y` and then the divided values get summed up after rounding up to two decimal places it shows the exact value `x`.

Here is the image of an example

[image]

Here we take an example where `x=10000` and `y=12` then values are shown from 1 to 12 column after division and 13 column shows its total.

Now `x` was `10000` and total that is coming is `9999.96`

so difference of `10000-9999.96 =0.04`

What actually the requirement is now i want to divide these `0.04` such that

`0.01` added in first month

`0.01` added in second month

---

`0.01` added in fourth month

Thus now total will become `10000`

How can i achieve this using  existing mysql query
as all these values 1 to 13 column are coming from mysql query

Comment: Why is this question tagged Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is pure math problem that can be rewritten as this:

```
x/y = z = (floor(100*x/y)/100)+d
```

where `z` is the wanted value and `d` is the rounding difference so

```
d=(x/y)-(floor(100*x/y)/100)
```

so the result should be

```
x/y = z = (floor(100*x/y)/100)+(x/y)-(floor(100*x/y)/100)
```

- `floor()` is round down to nearest smaller or equal integer
- `floor(100*x)/100` is round down up to 2 decimal places. If you rounding around `0.5` boundary instead of integer round down then use `floor((100*x)+0.5)/100` instead

Now the problem is that you are bound to 2 decimals so you need change the `d` to 2 decimal numbers let me rewrite the difference to.

```
D=d*y=d(0)+d(1)+d(2)+...+d(y-1)
```

So we have global difference `D` and set of differences per "moth" `d(i)`

```
D=x-((floor(100*x/y)/100)*y)
d(i)=         floor(100*D/y)/100    i = { 1,2,3,...,y-1 }
d(0)=D-(y-1)*(floor(100*D/y)/100)
```

And that is what you want to add to your cells ...

If you want to change the remainder of difference to be stored in multiple columns instead of just in `d(0)` then the remainders possible for `y=12` are:

```
{ 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, ... , 0.11 }
```

so you can use only `0.01` or `0.00` as difference between regular `d(i)` so you can rewrite

```
D=x-((floor(100*x/y)/100)*y)
d(i)=         floor(100*D/y)/100+0.01    i = <0 , y-1> AND i <  100*(D%y)
d(i)=         floor(100*D/y)/100         i = <0 , y-1> AND i >= 100*(D%y)
```

Hope I did not make some silly math mistake somewhere As i derived all inside SO editor ...

**[Edit1] C++ example of this:**

```
int i,n,y=12; double x=10000.00,fy=y,z,D,d,s;
z=floor((100.0*x)/fy)*0.01;         // cell value rounded
D=x-(z*fy);                         // global correction
n=floor((100.0*D)+0.5);             // iregular remainder
for (s=0.0,i=0;i<y;i++)
    {
    d=0.01*floor(100.0*D/y);        // regular local correction
    if (i<n) d+=0.01;               // iregular local correction
    // z+d is the new cell value and s is the sum for check ...
    s+=z+d;
    mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%3i: %5.2f",i,z+d));
    }
mm_log->Lines->Add("--------------");
mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("sum: %5.2f",s));
```

You can ignore `mm_log->Lines->...` it is just output to memo for visual check:

```
  0: 833.34
  1: 833.34
  2: 833.34
  3: 833.34
  4: 833.33
  5: 833.33
  6: 833.33
  7: 833.33
  8: 833.33
  9: 833.33
 10: 833.33
 11: 833.33
--------------
sum: 10000.00
```

If you got irregular `x` division (the `z` values are different) then just instead of `z*fy` use `z(0)+z(1)+z(2)+...+z(y-1)` and instead of `z` use `z(i)`. The value `fy` is the same as `y` but as float variable.

**[Notes]**

You should use `double` because `float` has too small mantissa to reliably round to `2` decimals with values around `10000`. You can also use pure `int` variables in that case no round errors are present but you're limited by the top value ...

You should also post the content of your **MySQL** table(s) and the Query you used if you are hoping for this **MySQL** example from someone...